# WebApi using sub-domain in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I have a domain with sub-domain setup for webapi:

1. Main Domain (www.abc.com)
2. Sub-Domain (api.abc.com)

Now the API domain accesses the logged in users shopping cart data via ASP.Net Membership and then via AJAX calls i access it on main domain (www.abc.com)

I am able to access the asp.net membership data in api.abc.com, however when i attempt to use AJAX function on my main site, at that time, the asp.net membership always returns null, because of which i am not able to access the Shopping cart details of the current logged in user.

I tried update following things but didn't worked:

1. Added entity framework section, so as to allow access to my database (web.config)
2. Ensured the Machine Key is same across both the domains so as to encryption to work (web.config)
3. Added CORS in Api Project, so as to allow destionation domain (www.abc.com) to be able to access it. (WebApiConfig.cs)

Here's my AJAX call to the api to pull shopping cart details:

```
$.getJSON([API URL], function (data) {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0)
            $(".right-side-toggle span.badge").html(data.length);
        else
            $(".right-side-toggle span.badge").html("0");
    });
```

Could anyone suggest what could be the issue, when making the AJAX call the Membership returns `NULL`

UPDATED

```
public List<ShoppingCartData> GetShoppingCart()
        {
            Guid _guid = new Guid();
            string whereClause = string.Empty;
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            if (user != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName))
            {
                _guid = new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                whereClause = " sc.UserId = '" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + "' ";
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Common.SHOPPING_CART_COOKIE] != null)
            {
                _guid = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Common.SHOPPING_CART_COOKIE].Value);
                whereClause = " sc.CartId = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Common.SHOPPING_CART_COOKIE].Value + "' ";
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            string query = "select scd.Id as ShoppingCartDetailsId, sc.CartId, p.ProductId, scd.Quantity, p.[Name], p.[Description], p.OurPrice, p.MaximumRetailPrice, pi.[Image], p.CurrencyId from dbo.ShoppingCart sc " +
                "inner join dbo.ShoppingCartDetails scd " +
                "on sc.CartId = scd.CartId " +
                "inner join dbo.Product p " +
                "on scd.ProductId = p.ProductId " +
                "inner join dbo.ProductToImages pi " +
                "on p.ProductId = pi.ProductId " +
                "where " + whereClause + "" +
                "and ISNULL(sc.IsCheckoutProcessed, 0) = 0";

            return db.Database.SqlQuery<ShoppingCartData>(query).ToList();
        }
```

The above code is in a separate assembly which is targeted in both (API and main domain (www.abc.com))

Comment: Isn't it session related? Can you post some code from the api where it would return membership data when you target it directly and where it's null when accessed from the `www` subdomain through Ajax?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code for the shopping cart.